# Three bucket water puzzle

Tags: puzzle

You have three buckets, two big buckets holding `8 litres` of water each and one small empty bucket that can hold `3 litres` of water. How will you split the `16 litres` of water to `four people` evenly? Each person has a container but once water is distributed to someone it cannot be taken back.

In this puzzle, we need to allocate 4 litres to each person. So I considered the initial state as below

> 8 8 0 [0, 0, 0, 0]

The values in the bracket are the water given to those 4 people.
I tried the below steps

> 5 8 3 [0, 0, 0, 0] 
>   5 8 0 [3, 0, 0, 0] 
>   5 5 3 [3, 0, 0, 0] 
>   5 5 0 [3, 3, 0, 0] 
>   2 8 0 [3, 3, 0, 0] 
>   0 8 2 [3, 3, 0, 0] 
>   0 7 3 [3, 3, 0, 0] 
>   0 4 3 [3, 3, 3, 0] 
>   0 1 3 [3, 3, 3, 3] 
>   0 0 3 [4, 3, 3, 3]

But I couldnt take it further by giving those 1 litre for rest of the 3 persons since there is a constraint that water given to person cant be retrieved back. 
Any help/hint towards final solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far*. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Sure. Let me update the question now.

Comment: @sundar: Is the water in the big buckets to begin with, or is it in another container?

Comment: @Dennis: The question is rather clear in that respect: The big buckets are "holding" water and the small one is empty and "can hold" water.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
8 8 0 [0 0 0 0]
8 5 3 [0 0 0 0]
8 5 0 [3 0 0 0]
8 2 3 [3 0 0 0]
8 0 3 [3 2 0 0]
8 3 0 [3 2 0 0]
5 3 3 [3 2 0 0]
5 6 0 [3 2 0 0]
2 6 3 [3 2 0 0]
2 8 1 [3 2 0 0]
2 8 0 [3 2 1 0]
0 8 2 [3 2 1 0]
0 7 3 [3 2 1 0]
3 7 0 [3 2 1 0]
3 4 3 [3 2 1 0]
6 4 0 [3 2 1 0]
6 1 3 [3 2 1 0]
6 0 3 [3 2 1 1]
8 0 1 [3 2 1 1]
8 0 0 [4 2 1 1]
5 0 3 [4 2 1 1]
5 3 0 [4 2 1 1]
2 3 3 [4 2 1 1]
0 3 3 [4 4 1 1]
0 0 3 [4 4 4 1]
0 0 0 [4 4 4 4]
```

Comment: +1 Nice! Any particular approach to do this, better than trial and error?

Comment: @polkjh: The only insights I remember having are a) I was always trying to do it with $3+1$ and I needed to include some $2$s, and b) a $1$ or $2$ needed to be dispensed whenever possible, preferably a $1$, to produce as many $1$s and $2$s as possible early on, since that's no longer possible once you only have $6$ litres left.

Comment: Is the 6th line redundant?

Comment: @John: You mean you could go directly from the $5$th to the $7$th? I don't think so. The first two numbers stand for the big buckets (as in the OP's notation); you can't just pour $3$ litres from one big bucket into the other without using the small bucket to measure them.

Answer (score 0):

Above can be completed in 13 steps:

`8,8,0[0,0,0,0]
8,5,3[0,0,0,0]
8,5,0[3,0,0,0]
5,5,3[3,0,0,0]
5,5,0[3,3,0,0]
5,2,3[3,3,0,0]
5,2,0[3,3,3,0]
5,0,2[3,3,3,0]
4,0,3[3,3,3,0]
0,0,3[3,3,3,4]
0,0,2[4,3,3,4]
0,0,1[4,4,3,4]
0,0,0[4,4,4,4]`

Comment: Some of the last steps are not allowed, because they require you to measure out $1$ litre. Once you get to `0,0,3 [3,3,3,4]`, you're stuck, because you can only transfer the $3$ litres back and forth without being able to split it up properly.