# Two Buckets Water Puzzle

Tags: graph-theory, puzzle

When reading up on graph theory, I came across [this puzzle](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/CartWater.shtml) and on further investigation, learned that a general solution for this is similar to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324594/three-bucket-water-puzzle?s=2|0.6916).

However, I haven't been able to understand how a graph may be used (though I did come across [this animation](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/WaterPouringProblem/)). I'm trying to come up with an algorithm where, given two buckets of capacities *a* and *b*, how can I come up with the least number of steps to obtain precisely *k* litres? Since I originally saw the question in relation to a chapter on graph theory, I would love some pointers on how this may be solved using graphs (as opposed to the seemingly more commong gcd method).

EDIT: I found [another related solution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5800/generalization-of-the-two-bucket-puzzle) but am still not entirely certain.

Comment: As for how to describe the problem with graphs, [if you went a bit further down the page](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/wgraph.shtml) you would have seen a similar problem where they describe the graph-theoretical approach.  Essentially, it involves describing each possible state as a vertex, and transitions from one state to another as edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that an ordered pair representing an amount of water one can obtain in each bucket represents a node in a graph. The directed edges of the graph represent which states are obtainable in one move from the current state.

Solving for the least number of steps to obtain precisely $k$ liters is then a shortest path problem. You are searching the graph for the shortest path from the original state to a state that has $k$ as one the members of the ordered pair.

Comment: Typical graphs of this kind are shown in https://vixra.org/abs/1509.0140 .